# Check whether the string field in data class within ArrayList has the given value

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList` of data class named `Customer`:

```
public class Customer {

    private String userid;
    private String fullName;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String email;
    private String addressOne;
    private String addressTwo;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String zip;
    private String country;

    public String getUserid() {
        return userid;
    }

    public void setUserid(String userid) {
        this.userid = userid;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }

    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getAddressOne() {
        return addressOne;
    }

    public void setAddressOne(String addressOne) {
        this.addressOne = addressOne;
    }

    public String getAddressTwo() {
        return addressTwo;
    }

    public void setAddressTwo(String addressTwo) {
        this.addressTwo = addressTwo;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public String getZip() {
        return zip;
    }

    public void setZip(String zip) {
        this.zip = zip;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }
}
```

I create array list of customers

```
ArrayList<Customer> customersList = new ArrayList<Customer>();
```

and I load the `ArrayList` with many customers in a loop.

How can I check if a customer with the name `"David Paul"` is already in the `ArrayList`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
boolean contains = customersList.stream()
                     .anyMatch(c -> c.getFullName().equals("David Paul"));
```

Comment: it works, I will accept it in 10 minutes when stackoverflow allows. But c -> c is new syntax to me. What is this called?

Comment: Would `contains()` suffice?

Comment: @DizzyCode Not in this case, I think because I'm using a dataclass and not a string

Comment: @Arya ``c -> ...`` is the lambda notation introduced in Java 8

Comment: @Arya you can override the `equals` method in that class to only use `fullName` if you're not using it anywhere else, then `contains` will work but still will be slow.

Comment: @MateuszDymczyk thanks for the suggestion, but my client will be using this with customers less than 100 each time, so performance won't be an issue. I do like your approach though.

Comment: @Arya To build off of Jean Logeart's last comment, the code that is in the anyMatch() is what is called a Predicate, or a function if you will.  stream().anyMatch() is iterating each item in the List and each object get's assigned to the temporary variable c, which is automatically typed as a Customer object.  That's what allows for c.getFullName().

Answer (score 3):

With an `ArrayList` you'll have to simply traverse the whole list element by element and check if a given customer is there. This will be slow (`O(n^2)` slow).

If you can changing a list to a `Set` would be a preferred way, then you can just override the `hashCode` and `equals` methods to use `fullName` and check it in constant time using `set.contains()`. Or you can make a `Map` of `<String, Customer>` where the keys will be `fullName` and again you can check in constant time whether a given key is present.

If you need to keep the order of insertions you can use something like `LinkedHashMap` or `LinkedHashSet`.

Comment: Going through the list is O(n). Then two customers are not necessarily because they have the same name. Also it does not really answer the OP question.

Comment: @JeanLogeart as I understood the question, the OP wants to check it before each insert while reading the data which will be in the end `O(n^2)` (should all customers be unique). And how does my answer not answer his question? I told him that with a list he needs to traverse the whole list or change the data structure. I did not write his code for him but that doesn't mean I did not answer his question.

Comment: @MateuszDymczyk Your approach is very good, but since I tried Jean's answer first and the list my program works with is very small I accepted his. I did do a upvote on your answer though.

Comment: @Arya no problem, not doing this for points :-) Have a look at Sets and Maps just for future reference, though! And maybe change that first `ArrayList` to a `List` if you don't explicitly need `ArrayList` methods :-)

Comment: Dumczyk, could you explain to me why your solution just takes constant time? yes you can access it this way, but then you reduce a comparison for the whole program to the full name... we do not know to much about the program, but especially in larger projects I would not suggest to do it like you said. does it make sense? hopefully...

Comment: @Anton I never said the whole thing takes constant time, only the check against the collection goes down from `O(n)` to `O(1)`. The OP said he only wants to use `fullName` for comparison. If he wants to use `equals` in other way somewhere else then he can use the `Map` approach and use `fullName` as keys. It's a simple tradeoff and depends on the use case, that's why I proposed 3 solutions.

Comment: alright I just wanted to point out the problem with changing the equals method. and with the constant time, I just got you wrong, sorry mate